# Requests in multiprocessing fail python

Tags: python, multithreading, python-requests, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I'm trying to query data from a website, but it takes 6 seconds to query. For all 3000 of my queries, I'd be sitting around for 5 hours. I heard there was a way to parallelize this stuff, so I tried using multiprocessing to do it. It didn't work, and I tried asyncio, but it gave much the same result. Here's the multiprocessing code since that's simpler.

I have 5+ urls in a list I want to request tables from:

https://irsa.ipac.caltech.edu/cgi-bin/Gator/nph-query?outfmt=1&searchForm=MO&spatial=cone&catalog=neowiser_p1bs_psd&moradius=5&mobj=smo&mobjstr=1&btime=2014+01+17+18:38:41&etime=2014+01+18+18:38:41&selcols=w1mpro,w1sigmpro,w1snr,w1rchi2,w1flux,w1sigflux,w1sky,w1mag_2,w1sigm,mjd
https://irsa.ipac.caltech.edu/cgi-bin/Gator/nph-query?outfmt=1&searchForm=MO&spatial=cone&catalog=neowiser_p1bs_psd&moradius=5&mobj=smo&mobjstr=2&btime=2014+05+18+23:10:01&etime=2014+05+19+23:10:01&selcols=w1mpro,w1sigmpro,w1snr,w1rchi2,w1flux,w1sigflux,w1sky,w1mag_2,w1sigm,mjd
https://irsa.ipac.caltech.edu/cgi-bin/Gator/nph-query?outfmt=1&searchForm=MO&spatial=cone&catalog=neowiser_p1bs_psd&moradius=5&mobj=smo&mobjstr=3&btime=2014+11+04+06:01:27&etime=2014+11+05+06:01:27&selcols=w1mpro,w1sigmpro,w1snr,w1rchi2,w1flux,w1sigflux,w1sky,w1mag_2,w1sigm,mjd
https://irsa.ipac.caltech.edu/cgi-bin/Gator/nph-query?outfmt=1&searchForm=MO&spatial=cone&catalog=neowiser_p1bs_psd&moradius=5&mobj=smo&mobjstr=4&btime=2014+07+14+10:01:45&etime=2014+07+15+10:01:45&selcols=w1mpro,w1sigmpro,w1snr,w1rchi2,w1flux,w1sigflux,w1sky,w1mag_2,w1sigm,mjd
https://irsa.ipac.caltech.edu/cgi-bin/Gator/nph-query?outfmt=1&searchForm=MO&spatial=cone&catalog=neowiser_p1bs_psd&moradius=5&mobj=smo&mobjstr=5&btime=2014+07+04+20:17:01&etime=2014+07+05+20:17:01&selcols=w1mpro,w1sigmpro,w1snr,w1rchi2,w1flux,w1sigflux,w1sky,w1mag_2,w1sigm,mjd

Here's my request code:

```
from astropy.io import fits
from astropy.io import ascii as astro_ascii
from astropy.time import Time

def get_real_meta(url):
  
    df = astro_ascii.read(url)
    df=df.to_pandas()
    print(df)

    return df

import multiprocessing as mp
pool = mp.Pool(processes=10)
results = pool.map(get_real_meta, urls)
```

When I run this, some of the results are failed requests.

Why is this happening?

This is the full result from the run:

```
                  col1  \
0  [struct stat="ERROR"   

                                                    col2  \
0  msg="ERROR: Cannot process Moving Object Correctly. "   

                                                                                                      col3  
0  logfile="https://irsa.ipac.caltech.edu:443/workspace/TMP_1YL1MV_20034/Gator/irsa/20034/log.20034.html"]  
                   col1  \
0  [struct stat="ERROR"   

                                                    col2  \
0  msg="ERROR: Cannot process Moving Object Correctly. "   

                                                                                                      col3  
0  logfile="https://irsa.ipac.caltech.edu:443/workspace/TMP_gteaoW_20031/Gator/irsa/20031/log.20031.html"]  
                   col1  \
0  [struct stat="ERROR"   

                                                    col2  \
0  msg="ERROR: Cannot process Moving Object Correctly. "   

                                                                                                      col3  
0  logfile="https://irsa.ipac.caltech.edu:443/workspace/TMP_yWl2vY_20037/Gator/irsa/20037/log.20037.html"]  
    cntr_u    dist_x      pang_x        ra_u      dec_u          ra  \
0        1  2.338323  -43.660587  153.298036  13.719689  153.297574   
1        2  1.047075   96.475058  153.337711  13.730126  153.338009   
2        3  1.709365 -159.072115  153.377399  13.740497  153.377224   
3        4  0.903435   84.145005  153.377439  13.740491  153.377696   
4        5  0.800164   99.321042  153.397283  13.745653  153.397509   
5        6  0.591963   16.330683  153.417180  13.750790  153.417228   
6        7  0.642462   63.761302  153.437090  13.755910  153.437255   
7        8  1.020182 -123.497531  153.457013  13.761012  153.456770   
8        9  1.051963  130.842143  153.476909  13.766102  153.477137   
9       11  1.007540  -55.156815  153.516820  13.776216  153.516583   
10      12  0.607295  118.463910  153.556744  13.786265  153.556897   
11      13  0.227240  -79.964079  153.556784  13.786259  153.556720   
12      14  1.526454 -113.268004  153.596760  13.796237  153.596359   

          dec          clon          clat  w1mpro  w1sigmpro  w1snr  w1rchi2  \
0   13.720159  10h13m11.42s  13d43m12.57s   7.282      0.014   78.4   307.90   
1   13.730093  10h13m21.12s  13d43m48.34s   6.925      0.018   59.8    82.35   
2   13.740054  10h13m30.53s  13d44m24.19s   6.354      0.012   91.3   203.90   
3   13.740517  10h13m30.65s  13d44m25.86s   6.862      0.015   70.3    61.03   
4   13.745617  10h13m35.40s  13d44m44.22s   7.005      0.016   68.0    62.28   
5   13.750948  10h13m40.13s  13d45m03.41s   6.749      0.015   70.4    26.35   
6   13.755989  10h13m44.94s  13d45m21.56s   7.031      0.019   57.5    37.56   
7   13.760856  10h13m49.62s  13d45m39.08s   6.729      0.013   84.9    66.91   
8   13.765911  10h13m54.51s  13d45m57.28s   6.944      0.022   49.0    44.22   
9   13.776376  10h14m03.98s  13d46m34.95s   7.049      0.022   49.1    20.63   
10  13.786185  10h14m13.66s  13d47m10.26s   6.728      0.018   58.9    14.40   
11  13.786270  10h14m13.61s  13d47m10.57s   6.773      0.024   45.3    10.65   
12  13.796069  10h14m23.13s  13d47m45.85s   7.126      0.015   72.2   219.50   

      w1flux  w1sigflux   w1sky  w1mag_2  w1sigm           mjd  
0   248830.0     3173.5  24.057    7.719   0.013  56795.965297  
1   345700.0     5780.5  27.888    8.348   0.006  56796.096965  
2   584870.0     6406.8  24.889    7.986   0.006  56796.228504  
3   366210.0     5206.7  27.876    7.653   0.006  56796.228632  
4   321210.0     4725.7  26.150    7.867   0.009  56796.294338  
5   406400.0     5771.4  25.240    7.711   0.006  56796.360172  
6   313360.0     5449.7  26.049    7.988   0.006  56796.426005  
7   414100.0     4877.9  25.581    8.022   0.006  56796.491839  
8   339610.0     6935.9  25.564    8.029   0.007  56796.557545  
9   308370.0     6285.2  25.491    8.331   0.006  56796.689212  
10  414410.0     7035.5  27.656    7.851   0.007  56796.820752  
11  397500.0     8773.4  27.628    8.015   0.006  56796.820880  
12  287270.0     3980.2  24.825    8.310   0.006  56796.952419  
    cntr_u    dist_x      pang_x        ra_u     dec_u          ra       dec  \
0        1  0.570817  137.605512  128.754979  4.242103  128.755086  4.241986   
1        2  0.852021   14.819525  128.791578  4.225474  128.791639  4.225703   
2        3  1.099000   -4.816139  128.828083  4.208860  128.828057  4.209164   
3        4  1.207022    9.485091  128.864456  4.192260  128.864511  4.192591   
4        5  0.323112  107.976317  128.882608  4.183966  128.882694  4.183938   
5        6  0.627727   99.373708  128.882645  4.183967  128.882817  4.183939   
6        7  0.489166   19.732971  128.900773  4.175676  128.900819  4.175804   
7        8  0.231292 -139.425350  128.918877  4.167389  128.918835  4.167340   
8        9  0.393206  -28.705753  128.936958  4.159106  128.936905  4.159202   
9       10  0.466548  -35.199460  128.936995  4.159107  128.936920  4.159213   
10      11  1.153921 -100.879703  128.955053  4.150828  128.954737  4.150767   
11      12  1.078232  -38.005043  128.973087  4.142552  128.972902  4.142788   
12      13  1.172329  -27.290606  128.991097  4.134280  128.990947  4.134569   
13      15  1.399220   54.717544  129.027083  4.117750  129.027401  4.117974   

            clon          clat  w1mpro  w1sigmpro  w1snr  w1rchi2    w1flux  \
0   08h35m01.22s  04d14m31.15s   6.768      0.018   58.9   60.490  395130.0   
1   08h35m09.99s  04d13m32.53s   6.706      0.018   59.1   30.780  418160.0   
2   08h35m18.73s  04d12m32.99s   6.754      0.024   45.4   20.520  400280.0   
3   08h35m27.48s  04d11m33.33s   6.667      0.024   44.9   34.090  433390.0   
4   08h35m31.85s  04d11m02.18s   6.782      0.023   47.8    9.326  389870.0   
5   08h35m31.88s  04d11m02.18s   6.710      0.035   31.4   11.360  416570.0   
6   08h35m36.20s  04d10m32.89s   6.880      0.021   52.7    7.781  356410.0   
7   08h35m40.52s  04d10m02.42s   6.653      0.023   46.8   18.900  439130.0   
8   08h35m44.86s  04d09m33.13s   6.986      0.023   47.2    8.576  323350.0   
9   08h35m44.86s  04d09m33.17s   6.917      0.019   58.5   25.720  344400.0   
10  08h35m49.14s  04d09m02.76s   6.782      0.015   70.1  173.800  390170.0   
11  08h35m53.50s  04d08m34.04s   6.671      0.016   69.6   70.490  431820.0   
12  08h35m57.83s  04d08m04.45s   7.152      0.016   66.6  131.100  277440.0   
13  08h36m06.58s  04d07m04.71s   6.436      0.017   63.3   86.350  536630.0   

    w1sigflux   w1sky  w1mag_2  w1sigm           mjd  
0      6711.7  21.115    7.988   0.008  56965.251016  
1      7070.1  23.748    7.830   0.007  56965.382556  
2      8812.6  20.930    8.456   0.007  56965.514096  
3      9649.6  21.350    8.120   0.008  56965.645509  
4      8161.1  19.988    7.686   0.007  56965.711215  
5     13264.0  22.180    7.902   0.016  56965.711343  
6      6769.0  22.962    8.023   0.008  56965.777049  
7      9382.2  22.355    8.030   0.007  56965.842755  
8      6847.6  23.531    8.024   0.007  56965.908462  
9      5882.5  21.256    7.654   0.007  56965.908589  
10     5568.7  21.926    8.051   0.007  56965.974295  
11     6202.3  23.497    7.950   0.007  56966.040002  
12     4165.8  20.094    8.091   0.010  56966.105708  
13     8482.9  22.436    8.191   0.008  56966.237248
```

Comment: `multiprocessing` is incredibly heavy for this kind of work because it's I/O bound, not CPU bound; it's not meant for this. You would be better using asynchronous requests (as with `asyncio` or my favourite [`requests-futures`](https://pypi.org/project/requests-futures/) which is very slightly slower but much more familiar syntax)

Comment: In any case, those are not python errors but look like they come from parse errors in `astropy`, which I'm not familiar with.

Comment: Although, saying that, you're not using standard requests and the data in the links will require parsing, which apparently `astro_ascii` will do, so maybe you are stuck with `multiprocessing`. Still, they are not python errors

Comment: As pointed out by roganjosh, `astro_ascii.read` is IO-bound and more specifically latency-bound. This function accepts file-like objects like StringIO according to the doc, so you can download the content of all the pages and then load them efficiently using asynchronous IO. It should be much faster than multiprocessing since there can be more pending requests than the number of running processes and there is no inter-process communication to pay.

Comment: I tried using requests to get the content of each page as well, and it gives similar server errors there, too. I don't think it has anything to do with the actual read process, but I might be wrong. Could it be possible that the server is preventing multiple requests?